# Como passar dados do mapa para ser exibido por outra classe?

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, google-maps, uiview

Estou usando a API Maps da Google para iOS. Estava fazendo alguns testes e ajustei uma `UIView` como subclasse de `GMSMapView` e mantive um ponteiro para ela na `ViewController`, ficando:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<GMSMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet GMSMapView *meuMapa;

@end
```

E fiz sua implementação em outra classe, deste modo:

```
-(GMSMapView*)criaMapa{
 // Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the
    // coordinate -33.86,151.20 at zoom level 6.
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition
                                 cameraWithLatitude:-22.530351
                                 longitude:-43.071199
                                 zoom:17];
    _mapaCriado = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];

    #pragma mark - Coloca Pinos no Mapa

    // Uma posição em Niteroi
    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-22.530303,-43.071033);
    marker.title = @"Ponto B";
    marker.snippet = @"Detalhes";

    marker.map = _mapaCriado;

    return _mapaCriado;
}
```

Voltando em `ViewController.m` no método `-(void)viewDidLoad` eu recebo o mapa que foi criado em outra classe:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    CriaMapas mapFact = [[CriaMapas alloc]init];
    self.meuMapa = [mapFact criaMapa];
}
```

Porém o mapa é iniciado sem nada, como se não houvesse feito inicialização e nenhuma criação de *Marker*.

Como poderia fazer isso: Criar o mapa em outra classe e retornar ele para ser exibido?

Answer (score 1):

Acontece que você não pode simplesmente atribuir ao **meuMapa** um outro `GMSMapView`, além desse primeiro ser um `IBOutlet`.

Como a criação do seu mapa é feito de forma dinâmica, você precisa também adicionar o mapa à sua *view* desta mesma forma. Então, esse `IBOutlet` pode ser substituído por uma View base que irá receber o mapa:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *mapaContainer;
```

E então, criar a adicionar o mapa como *subview* desta acima:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    CGRect rect = [mapaContainer frame];
    CriaMapas mapFact = [[CriaMapas alloc] init];

    GMSMapView meuMapa = [mapFact criaMapa];
    [meuMapa setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, [rect.size width], [rect.size height])];

    [self.mapaContainer addSubview:meuMapa];
}
```

Você pode também alterar seu método `criaMapa` para poder receber direto as dimensões do mapa, assim não precisa definir o *frame* do lado de fora.

Comment: o IBOutlet é um UIView adicionado pelo Interface Build, e a classe GMSMapView é atribuída a ela, então eu so atribuo a ele as informações do mapa na própria ViewController e funciona... Achei que eu poderia atribuir um GMSMapView iniciada em outro objeto a ele também.... mas será que não existe um modo de ter uma "fabrica" de mapa?

Vou dar mais uma pesquisada.... Vlw!

Comment: Cara, fiz um teste somente instanciando e passando Marker... e faz mais sentido :D. É possivel fazer isso com GMSMarker.

Vlw!

Comment: Sim, é a outra forma realmente mais prática, já que o mapa já foi criado pelo *interface builder*, pois não há necessidade de criar duas vezes. Ou cria ele dinamicamente ou pela interface, a após atribui as características e etc.